# I want certain page to be cookiless

Tags: asp.net

Is there a way to make a certain page work as a cookieless session? while the rest of the website is allowing cookies, I want to call a page Back from another page Front, like this

folder/(session id)/Back and then forward the response from page page Front to Page back is that impossible.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible with the built in session mechanism since it's a site wide setting.

You would have to create your custom session state mechanism if this feature is mandatory for your site.

Answer (score 0):

Cookieless sessions are not very secure (the querystring can be sniffed), but SSL can help a little (the querystring is encrypted). You probably shouldnt be using them anyway

Are you really talking about changing the behavior of the back/forward buttons? What is "Page Front/Back"?

Comment: So, you want to share variable values across pages?